# Problem getting STM32 debugging to work

Tags: stm32, stm32f10x, workbench, stm32f103c8t6

Yesterday I debugged a program on my STM32F103C8T6 with Eclipse STM32 workbench without any problem.

Today I tried the same but constantly get this error.

[image]

What I tried to fix:

- Erase the chip with ST-Link Utility successfully
- Restarted the STM32 workbench
- Removed power
- Replugged (in different USB port) the ST-Link

Nothing of these actions helped.

What can I do to be able to debug again?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem ... there was an openocd task still running.
Ending the process inside the Task Manager removes the process, which results in not showing the error screen when starting to debug.